# Recaptcha v3 action as argument

Tags: vue.js, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I use vue-recaptcha with recaptcha v3.
I want to find a way to send the action also.

The google manual says that the action should be sent in the execute function:

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         ...
      });
  });
```

but inside vue-recaptcha code execute is called by widget ID only:

```
execute: function execute(widgetId) {
        if (typeof widgetId === 'undefined') {
          return;
        }

        this.assertLoaded();
        this.wait().then(function () {
          return window.grecaptcha.execute(widgetId);
        });
      },
```

Is there a way to specify the recaptcha action in the html?

Or is there other way to hack the vue-recaptcha js code to include the action?